# A nice lemma one the eigenvalues of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$
 $\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1|}$
Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix, and $(e_1,...,e_n)$ and orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $P_{ij} = \ket{e_i} \bra{e_i} + \ket{e_j} \bra{e_j}$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\text{span}(e_i,e_j)$, and we look at $P_{ij} M P_{ij}$ as $2 \times 2$ matrices (as their restriction to $\text{span}(e_i,e_j)$). The matrices $P_{ij} M P_{ij}$ are also symmetric. How to prove that
\begin{align*}
  \forall i,j \in \{1, ...,n \}, P_{ij} M P_{ij} \text{ has two different eigenvalues }  \\ \iff \text{ all the eigenvalues of $M$ are different}
\end{align*}

Comment: What do you mean by the symbol vect$(e_i,e_j)$? And how can $P_{ij}MP_{ij}$ be $2\times2$? In order that $P_{ij}MP_{ij}$ is a valid matrix product, $P_{ij}$ must be $n\times n$.

Comment: Also, what is "*the* projection"? Do you mean an orthogonal projection?

Comment: Sorry vect is span, and we can look at $P_{ ij} M P_{ ij}$ as $2 \times 2$ matrices by restriction, and the projection is the orthogonal one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true. Suppose $n=3,\,\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and
$$
M=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&\frac13&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\\ 0&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}&\frac23}.
$$
The eigenvalues of $M$ are $1,1$ and $0$, but each of
$$
P_{12}MP_{12}\sim\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&\frac13},
\ P_{13}MP_{13}\sim\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&\frac23},
\ P_{23}MP_{23}\sim\pmatrix{\frac13&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\\ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}&\frac23}
$$
has two different eigenvalues (as none of them is a scalar matrix).

Comment: @Alfred I am not aware of any such criterion. Being entrywise nonzero does not help. You can make the $M$ in my example entrywise nonzero by replacing considering $QMQ^T$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$ that is close to $I$.